# using hash (#) symbol to indicate input newline of command to a database linkedlist C program?

Tags: c, database, hash, io, linked-list

hi i am doing a C database program based on linear single linked list due to my college project.
the problem that i dont understand yet is the input and output program.

well basically the input of program is should be like this

```
INSERT
001 // indicates patient's number
John // indicates patient's name
M // indicates patient's gender
#
002 
Mary
F
#
SELECT // which means print the list
* // indicates all the list to be print
#
EXIT
```

input is done and the following line is the outputs

```
Data is added.
#
Hospital ID : 001
Name : John
Gender : M
#
Hospital ID : 002
Name : Mary
Gender : F
#
```

that's all.
Here is what I've been doing (in description)

- first line is gets for a command
- then doing the while command is not exit and not the # symbol in char , i check the command if it's "INSERT or "SELECT" using strcmp, if its equal then
- the next line is gets for the input that is used in the linkedlist command, where i give a flag in int that if the command is insert it will ask for 3 times , or SELECT if it's the * in char symbol with strcmp it will deleteall
- so basically after it repeats (flag) times to ask for inputline (using gets) it will ask for command again (forgot to mention before that char[size]), if # is inputted
- so to print the command in order i enqueue them in my queue for printingoutput
- until EXIT is inputted , it keeps enqueue , otherwise it will dequeue until the queue is NULL ( put the queue front in char temp )

BUT the whole algorithm doesnt seem to work, since the program only works out correctly for INSERT function.

then i am going back to my C book and read about the macro , parameter and such and research the internet until i found the idea of defining # itself to be a command to ask for more command

BUT doesn't seem to quite understand how the thing works that way.
any idea of what i should be doing to get the proper input and output ?
using this kind of strcmp while and if , or define the # itself ?

thank you in advanced, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

The hashtag `#` is not meaningful in the input of your program unless you wrote your program for it to be.

The hashtag for preprocessing directives like `#include` or `#define` is meaningful **in a C source code file** (or a C header file). All your program is getting as an input is characters, not commands.